# Cant display blob image for mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have an issue that I have been working on for the better part of two days.

Let me start by saying I have looked at all related articles concerning this error.

I am trying to display a blob image from my database. No matter have I try to display it, it also shows the little image not found icon. [image: image not found]

If anyone has any ideas please let me know, Thank you.

```
  $conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo 'Connected';
}

$select_path = "select * from ads";

$var = mysqli_query($conn, $select_path);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($var)) {
    $image_path = $row["photo1"];
    echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($image_path).'"/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the image mime correctly.
for example:

```
data:image/png;base64,
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

(missed png,jpg and etc..)

Comment: I have tried that, each different file type (jpeg, png, jpg) still doesnt seem to work

Comment: I am now getting this error when I execute "function() { var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/jb-server-page?reloadServiceClientId=4'); ws.onmessage = function (msg) { if (msg.data === 'reload') { window.location.reload(); } if

Comment: (msg.data.startsWith('update-css ')) { var messageId = msg.data.substring(11); var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link'); for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { var link = links[i]; if (link.rel !== 'stylesheet') continue; var clonedLink = link.cloneNode(true); var newHref = link.href.replace(/(&|\?)jbUpdateLinksId=\d+/, "$1jbUpdateLinksId=" + messageId); if (newHref !== link.href) { clonedLink.href = newHref; } else { var

Comment: indexOfQuest = newHref.indexOf('?'); if (indexOfQuest >= 0) { // to support ?foo#hash clonedLink.href = newHref.substring(0, indexOfQuest + 1) + 'jbUpdateLinksId=' + messageId + '&' + newHref.substring(indexOfQuest + 1); } else { clonedLink.href += '?' + 'jbUpdateLinksId=' + messageId; } } link.replaceWith(clonedLink); } } }; })();